# variable longer than string

Tags: vb.net, string, encryption

I am not really that good with vb.net, but i am facing a problem. 
I have to convert a string into binary (thing i have done) but after that, I have to encrypt the string by combining it whith another string, also converted into binary.

Problem : I am broswing this result whith the help of a string y() , but the result has the dimension bigger that 32 bit and i get the error : {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}

how cand i solve this? 
Thanks

```
Dim preluare As String = TextBox5.Text    ' the binary text i have to encrypt
    Dim inter() As Char = preluare.ToCharArray
    Dim b As Integer = TextBox5.Text.Count

    Dim x As String = TextBox15.Text  ' the key of encryption
    Dim y() As Char = x.ToCharArray
    Dim bb As Integer = TextBox15.Text.Count
```

' the key has to be the same lenght as the initial text

```
    If b > x.Count Then
        While x.Count < b
            x = x + x
        End While
    End If


    If x.Count > b Then
        Dim w As Integer = x.Count
        x = x.Trim().Substring(w - b)
    End If
```

' xor operation

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To b - 1
        If inter(i) = "0" Then
            'MsgBox(i)
            If y(i) = "0" Then ' THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
                TextBox10.Text = TextBox10.Text + "0"
            Else
                TextBox10.Text = TextBox10.Text + "1"
            End If
        Else
            If inter(i) = "1" Then
                If y(i) = "0" Then 
                    TextBox10.Text = TextBox10.Text + "1"
                Else
                    TextBox10.Text = TextBox10.Text + "0"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the error was because size of `y()` bigger than 32 bit integer, how about using 64 bit integer data type as counter :

```
For i As Int64 = 0 To b - 1
    .......
    .......
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use unsigned variables like
uint16, uint32...